# Get plain response from AFNetworking 2.4.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, post, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm sending a POST request:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"method": @"login", @"email":@"email", @"password":@"password"};
[manager POST:@"http://www.apiwebsite.com" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

My responseObject is:

> JSON: <0d0a7b22 72657370 6f6e7365 223a224f 4b222c22 30223a22 6d61696c
>   696e675f 6b657922 2c223122 3a226239 65653766 34643238 64333730
>   30666663 37393734 65376665 66626663 3136227d>

But calling the api with POSTMAN i get:

> {"response":"OK", "id":"1234223123"}

How can I get the plain or JSON response to work with it?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get JSON object use proper serializer `AFJSONResponseSerializer` instead of `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` you uses now.

For debug purpose convert `NSData` to `NSString` 
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@",  [[NSString alloc] initWithData: responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

Comment: If I use `AFJSONResponseSerializer ` I get:


`Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0x8c47a60 `

Comment: @pekpon did you set `requestSerializer`?

Comment: the problem is that `AFJSONResponseSerializer`only accepts `application/json - text/json - text/javascript`and I'm reciving `"Content-Type" = "text/html";`

Comment: @pekpon you are right, but type of response related to request's **Accept** header, see inside AFNetworking how it work, or google about accept header in http